# Terminal cp won't copy path folders with special characters within for loop?

Tags: bash, unicode, terminal, tmux, cp

I'm working on a bash script to recursively copy dated folders from a Time Machine backup, and subsequently deduplicate.  As expected, the cp (copy) command copies the intended 'foldertocopy' correctly when used outside the loop and directly in terminal (-R and -L flags set) - but not when placed within the loop of the script, which only copies contents.  Is this due to a special character in the source path within the loop?  Escaping the ' ’s ' in the source path fails, with terminal indicating there's no source for cp.

The script reads a text file ($source) containing time machine dates into an array (DATES), then copies the intended folder to the new destination.  The new destination path is constructed from user input (i.e. read -p "Destination" dest).

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a DATES < $source
for date in "${DATES[@]}"
do
    cp -RL /Volumes/Time\ Machine\ Backups/Backups.backupdb/Stix\'s’s\ MacBook\ Pro/$date/Macintosh\ HD/Users/foldertocopy /$dest/$date/$name
done
```

When cp is in the loop, the foldertocopy contents are copied as though there is no -R flag set.

What do I change to have the directory copied instead of the contents?

Update:
Using the unicode sequence in the path works, although in this case wasn't necessary.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -d /Volumes/Time\ Machine\ Backups/Backups.backupdb/Stix*` ? (I just want to see what that directory name really looks like.) Also, add double-quotes around *all* the variables used in the `cp` command, for example `"$date"`, `"$dest/$date/$name"`

Comment: Output is:  /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/Stix's’s MacBook Pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see these variables used in the `cp` command's arguments:

- `$date`
- `$dest`
- `$name`

If not enclosed in double-quotes, and if they contain spaces or other special characters, that will break the command.

The `cp` command will be safer and simpler to write like this:

```
cp -RL "/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/Stix's’s MacBook Pro/$date/Macintosh HD/Users/foldertocopy" "/$dest/$date/$name"
```

Also I have a doubt about this folder name:

```
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/Stix's’s MacBook Pro
```

Are you sure you have `'s’s` in there? Verify the correct name.
(What is the output of `ls -d "/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/Stix"*`?)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I went back and tried it again, with both the source and destination in double quotes, but it still doesn't work when used within the loop.  There are no special characters in $date, $dest, or $name.  I suspect the " ’s " is causing problems, as it's in the decomposed form when dragging and dropping the path into terminal (from the Time Machine Volume), which works, but I'm not sure how to ensure it's decomposed within the script.

Comment: @Stix What do you mean by "doesn't work within the loop"? And, does it work without a loop? (with a specific `$date` value)

Comment: cp -RL "/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/Stix's’s MacBook Pro/dateofTMcopy/Macintosh HD/Users/foldertocopy" "/destination" -- works in Terminal with drag and drop....copies foldertocopy correctly to the destination.  Once placed in a loop within a script, only the contents of the foldertocopy, are copied, which is the expected behavior without the -R flag.

Comment: @Stix maybe there's a confusion here. Given `source/x`, when `dest` exists, `cp -R source dest` will create `dest/source/x`, but when `dest` doesn't exist, `cp -R source dest` will create `dest/x`. Regardless of looping or drag & drop. Try it. If you want to make sure that `dest/source/x` gets created, then create `dest` before performing the `cp`. The `-R` does not mean that it creates this behavior for you. It just means that the copy will be recursive.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Yep, that was it, I neglected to create the intermediate folders first and was using /dest instead of dest.

Comment: For others wondering about the decomposed form of the " ’ ", it's stored that way in the editor (XCode).  However, assuming it's not, and assigning the " ’ " it's unicode sequence (\xe2\x80\x99) as a variable in the path, also works - use 'printf ’ | hexdump' to translate to unicode.